# Detecting and prevent click on scrollbar

Tags: javascript, html

For example, i have a similar React component:

```js
const result = document.getElementById('result');
const wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper');
function fireHandle(){
result.innerHTML = 'fire'
setTimeout(() => result.innerHTML = '', 1000)
}
wrapper.addEventListener("mousedown", fireHandle);
```

```css
#wrapper{
overflow: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
  max-width: 300px;
}

.box{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id='wrapper'>
<div class='box'></div>
<div class='box'></div>
<div class='box'></div>
<div class='box'></div>
<div class='box'></div>
<div class='box'></div>
</div>

<h1 id='result'></h1>
```

I have multiply mouse event listeners on wrapper element and i need to show scrollbar, but prevent all functions, if user clicked on scrollbar. For above example: if user clicked on scrollbar, 'fire' shouldn't appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compare the click position and the box-height to know whether you are clicking the scroll bar or not.

```js
const result = document.getElementById('result');
const wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper');
const box = document.querySelector('.box');

function fireHandle(e) {
const clickYPos = e.clientY - e.currentTarget.getBoundingClientRect().y;
const boxHeight = parseInt(getComputedStyle(box).height);
const offset = (wrapper.offsetHeight-boxHeight)/4;
  if (clickYPos-offset<=boxHeight) {
    result.innerHTML = 'fire'
    setTimeout(() => result.innerHTML = '', 1000)
  }

}
wrapper.addEventListener("mousedown", fireHandle);
```

```css
#wrapper {
  overflow: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
  max-width: 300px;
}

.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id='wrapper'>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
</div>

<h1 id='result'></h1>
```

Comment: i need to include space between boxes, so unfortunately this solution won't work

Comment: yeap, that's work, thank you! but i need to include area under boxes too, between box and scrollbax (it's 6px height, identically height of the scrollbar)

Comment: @A.Burdonskaya I added an offset. Did you mean the same ?